# is it okay to remove Laravel CSRF protection?

Tags: laravel, token

Is it okay to comment out or remove
`VerifyCsrfToken` class in my laravel middleware group?

Comment: if you dont want to be protected from anyone posting to your routes, sure

Comment: No need to modify VerifyCsrfToken middleware. Enough to remove it from the `App\Http\Kernel::$middlewareGroups` array.

Answer (score -2):

If you use the Laravel as Rest API (With Cors & JWT), there is no problem. But you're using The **blade** for forms, You need it absolutely!

Comment: CSRF is still an issue in a REST API if that API uses cookies for validation. Additionally, it's not Blade that's the issue - a non-Blade form (raw PHP, static HTML, etc.) would still have potential CSRF vulnerabilities.

Comment: @jfadich No, *sessions* are stateful. One could easily store a REST API's authentication token in a cookie. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints Every client request to a REST API endpoint should contain all the info required to execute it; that doesn't rule out cookies at all. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141019/should-cookies-be-used-in-a-restful-api

Comment: He can handle it by Cors without CSRF token and used the JWT for authenticating without cookies. So there is no problem. This related to architecture.

Comment: I require the auth_token on every request from the client in my stateless API, and removed the CSRF protection, is that okay?

Comment: @Kiani "Can" and "do" are not the same thing. A REST API is not *inherently* safe from CSRF; it is in *some* scenarios. Hence my clarifying comment. (CORS is entirely irrelevant; you can host a REST API on the same domain as the front-end, too.)

Comment: OK. I edited my comment. I thank you if you remove my downvote. Thank you.